# Fibre connection maxing out at 67mbps

Tags: networking, router, internet, lan, home-networking

My devices (all tested via wired connections) all seem to be maxing out at an extremely stable 67mbps / 19.5mbps. However my modem is showing 102mbps down the line. I'm in 100mbps package and was getting this speed before.

Eir (Irish ISP) support have confirmed that I'm getting full speed sent to my modem and that it may be an internal issue. I was actually told the phone connected to the same socket was showing interference, but surely I wouldn't be getting such a stable (but slower) connection?

I've since unplugged the landline and changed the DNS to Cloudflare. No improvement.

It's so strange that it's hovering at such a stable speed. It's as if I'm capped but Eir have said there's no speed profiling on my line.

Anyone experienced anything like this? Still running the F1000 (Zyxel manufactured) stock modem, by the way.

Comment: "Phone connected to the same socket"? That doesn't sound like fiber, that actually sounds like you got VDSL over copper phone-line?

Comment: @user1686 It's fibre-to-the-cabinet and then copper cable to house.

Comment: Right, so as long as that copper cable is DSL and not Ethernet, I'm inclined to suspect that's where the problem lies (all the speed and reliability of fiber ends at the cabinet)... Does your modem show any page with connection statistics, signal/noise ratios, etc.?

Comment: @user1686 It does and this has been analysed by the ISP. They are reporting zero interference externally, or internally.

Comment: @user1686 Attention on the line: 9.1dB / 8.2dB

Answer (score 1):

Your bandwidth is typical of
[VDSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSL)
profiles 12a and 12b.

Your ISP is probably using a Fiber to the Node (FTTN) deployment, where
profiles 8a-8b and 12a-12b are usually taken to be ideal.

The fiber node in your case is likely a street cabinet, connected over a
fiber optic line from the exchange. From there the connection is done over
the existing copper network to reach your premises.

In this case,
only your ISP can tell you if it is at all possible to upgrade your connection
to a higher profile via a higher frequency, or perhaps allow a direct
fiber connection to the house.
Although their equipment might not be capable of it.

This table summarizes the possible profiles in a compact manner:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Yes, it is indeed a FTTC setup. FTTH is unfortunately not available yet. The confusing thing is that we were getting higher speeds until recently.

Comment: If you were sold a 100 mbps package, you should really be on profile 17a. Try to get in touch with your ISP Support and ask to talk to a technician who could understand the terms.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks @harrymc. Wanted to make sure I wasn't going crazy before I called them back. Good to have this info to go back with.